Parent armature with a moving object
How can I parent an armature with an object that moves when you press play? I would like "armature.001" to move with the object.
Thank you
File: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/02c18cd625037279255ec59af24283be20240707130904/e8babce5b72ae06840ecb38914be55e520240707130932/c7754f

Hello could you please tell a bit more about your project and what you're trying to achieve, if the object is parented to the armature, you can't parent the armature to the object

Hi Moonboots, I want to have control of the general skillcape (t), especially at frame 250 because I don't want the general skillcape to merge into the character's body. The problem is that the rig does not move with the character. When the character gets to frame 250, I would like armature 001 to be there with him. Thank you :)

is this, what you wanna achieve?
select both armatures -> pose mode -> select bone cape.trim.l then shift select bone origin > ctrl-p -> bone
result:


Yes but the general skillcape falls downward in your gif.

of course you would have to bake the cloth sim again - i didn't do that, because that wasn't part of your question
